# If radio button is checked not running

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a div when a radio button is selected, but it's not running. I am including all the jQuery files etc and my console is showing no errors:

Input:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" id="international" name="international"/>
```

Javascript:

```
if($('#international').prop('checked') == true){
  alert('test');
  $("#internationalprice").show();
}
```

Comment: When you want to perform the above operation?

Comment: Correct. When running the above code

Comment: What's correct? You didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `change` event listener to the element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x18f4vh6/)

```
$('#international').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#internationalprice").show();
    }
});
```

---

If you wanted to achieve this without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vryo072k/)

```
document.getElementById('international').addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('internationalprice').style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: Duly noted for future jquery endeavours. Thanks bud.